# Intersect two feature layers with ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, intersection

I'm working to develop a spatial intersect between multiple featureLayers with ArcGIS API for JavaScript, and then I want to display just the intersected part on the map.

I have two featureLayers (RegionsLayer and CommunesLayer) so my goal is to get only the communes under a given Region, actually I can get a specific region with definitionExpression

```
 const featureLayerRegion = new FeatureLayer({
                    url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx/arcgis/rest/services/TEST_SPATIAL/MapServer/3",
                    outFields: ["*"],
                    definitionExpression: "ID_Reg = 1",
                    popupTemplate: templateRegion
                });
                map.add(featureLayerRegion);
```

and now I want to get all the communes from CommuneLayer that belong to this region ?

Comment: I think you are mixing up intersect operator of the Query (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/query-a-feature-layer-sql/#execute-a-query) with running an overlay operation on a server where the geometry service has intersect operation (https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/about-the-geometry-service.htm) or geometryEngine module of the API (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#intersect)

Comment: I have edited the question, as I need to get all the data that exist under a specific region, please check the question again.